# How to call connection method before any statement is executed

Tags: python, sql-server, sqlalchemy, pyodbc

I'm trying to connect to a database on an SQL Server via sqlalchemy. I can establish a connection via pyodbc, however, I have to call `conn.setencoding('utf-8')` on the connection to enable it to decode my queries (as described [here](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki/Unicode)).

In sqlalchemy, the very first time an engine establishes a connection, it queries the server version and issues some other test queries. These queries fail when setting up the engine normally, but I got them to work by using the `creator` parameter that `create_engine` takes. Alas, all subsequent queries still fail with the old `UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x80 in position 1: invalid start byte`, so it seems that the creator function is only called on the first connection. I expected it to be used for every connection, since that's what's stated in the [sqlalchemy docs](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/engines.html#sqlalchemy.create_engine):

> **creator** – a callable which returns a DBAPI connection. This creation function will be passed to the underlying connection pool and will be used to create all new database connections.

This is my setup:

```py
connectstring = f"DRIVER={DRIVER};" \
                f"SERVER={SERVER};" \
                f"PORT={PORT};" \
                f"DOMAIN={DOMAIN};" \
                f"USER={USER};" \
                f"PASSWORD={PASSWORD};" \
                f"DATASOURCE={DATASOURCE};" \
                f"ENCRYPT={ENCRYPT}"

def connect():
    conn = pyodbc.connect(connectstring)
    conn.setencoding('utf-8')
    return conn


engine = create_engine("mssql://", creator=connect, echo="debug", echo_pool="debug")
c = engine.connect()
```

So, my question is how to make sure that `.setencoding('utf-8')` is called on each newly created connection? I have already tried different PoolEvents (as described [here](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/events.html#sqlalchemy.events.PoolEvents)), but without luck.

**EDIT**:

pyodbc is version 4.0.25
sqlalchemy is version 1.2.16

Also, I am connecting to a Data Virtualization server which in turn accesses the SQL Server. I have already successfully established a connection to the SQL Server itself with sqlalchemy, so it seems to be that DV layer that introduces the problem.

Comment: It is strange that you need to use setencoding at all. SQL Server does not use UTF-8 encoding; it uses UTF-16LE, and UTF-16 is the default encoding used by pyodbc. What versions of pyodbc and SQLAlchemy are you using?

Comment: I've added the versions to the question. Maybe I should specify, I am connecting to a Data Virtualization server which in turn accesses the SQL Server. I have already successfully established a connection to the SQL Server itself with sqlalchemy, so it seems to be that DV layer that introduces the problem.

Comment: First step would be to upgrade pyodbc and SQLAlchemy to the latest versions (currently 4.0.26 and 1.3.5, respectively) and see if that helps.

Comment: Also, you might want to check if the DV layer really is supposed to be using UTF-8 in both directions. If it is sending back string data as a byte stream that begins with 0x80 then it isn't UTF-8 encoded (as the "invalid start byte" error indicates).

Comment: I think it is, I have updated both modules as you suggested and the decoding is indeed working now when using `setencoding("utf-8")`. I now have a different problem in that the DV layer does not use the same SQL syntax as the SQL server... but that's a different issue.